Automatically start a script before (or when) a solution is opened in Visual Studio
I have a solution with several projects inside and a python script which should do some maintaining tasks whenever I open the solution in VS. The issue is that often I forget to run it manually, so I thought there could be a way to do it this automatically. The script is in the the solution's directory, but the path to this directory itself might vary. I've heard that a custom extension to VS could do the trick to start the script when the solution with this name is executed but I have no good knowledge there. The version of Visual Studio I use (if that's matter) is VS Professional 2019.

For now, what I came up with a solution is to modify the script to open the solution file from with VS like this (Python):
import os

solution_file_path = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 
    'SolutionFileName.sln')
os.system(f'start "{visual_studio_path}" "{solution_file_path}"')

and then the script to continue as usual. The visual_studio_path string is retrieved from a text file inside the same same directory where the solution file is. This file is needed for other purposes and the user should populate it with the correct VS path anyway. So here I've got lucky with this. Here is how I did it:
def get_visual_studio_path_from_text_file(working_dir: str) -> Union[str, None]:
    file_path = os.path.join(working_dir, 'text_file_name.txt')
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            if line.startswith("visual.studio.home="):
                return line.split("=")[1].strip()
    return None

It is not the perfect solution for me because one should know to start the script in order to open the solution but not by the usual way (by double-clicking the solution file, opening it by VS, etc.) It would be much more elegant way the other way around - make VS to open the script when the solution is opened. So if you have an idea how this could be done, please do share!
